# Two divs side by side, but force the right div to stay above the left div if the screen is too small

Tags: html, css, positioning

The question title pretty much sums it up. I'm wondering if it's possible to have two divs side by side like:

DIV #1 | DIV #2

But then if the screen is too small (for example on a mobile device) I would like this to happen:

DIV #2

DIV #1

That is, DIV #1 slides down instead of DIV #2

Cheers,
Ben.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably use floats for the divs to sit next to each other. Use @media-queries to change this behaviour when the screen is too small. In your CSS file:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    /* when window size is below 480px */
    div {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

It's just an example which will set float:none to all divs on your website if the window size is smaller than 480px; adjust it to achieve what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CSS media query to check for the screen size in your positioning.

For example, the normal CSS would just have both elements floated left while your 320px style would have them as non floating.

You can use the min-width and max-width directive to check for this

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 900px)' href='css/medium.css' />
```

More details here - http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/